# In my treeview (python tkinter), when I add data, I want the data to be added based on parent name (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

In my TreeView I enter values manually, I would like to have them displayed like this:

```
Parent name1

child 1 

child 2 
   
child 3 

parent name 2 

child 1 

child 2
```

The data that I enter should be added as a child to the respective parent every time I enter (the entered parent name should be checked with pre-existing parent names in treeview).
Note: The data is entered into TreeView only if the failure rate is a numeric value.

```
#treeview
my_tree = ttk.Treeview(tree_frame,height= 15, yscrollcommand=tree_scroll.set)
my_tree.pack()

tree_scroll.config(command=my_tree.yview)

my_tree['columns'] = ("fun"," rate", "cv", "id")

my_tree.column("#0",width=100)
my_tree.column("fun",anchor=W,width=100)
my_tree.column("rate",anchor=W,width=100)
my_tree.column("cv",anchor=W,width=120)
my_tree.column("id",anchor=W,width=120)

my_tree.heading("#0",text='name',anchor=W)
my_tree.heading("fun", text='Fun', anchor=W)
my_tree.heading("rate",text='rate',anchor=W)
my_tree.heading("cv", text='Cv',anchor=W)
my_tree.heading("id",text='id',anchor=W)

main.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First all `ieX` are `None` because it is the result of `.grid(...)`.  You need to split the line like:

```py
ie1 = Entry(input_frame, width = 50).grid(row=0, column=1,padx=5,pady=5)
```

into two lines:

```
ie1 = Entry(input_frame, width = 50)
ie1.grid(row=0, column=1,padx=5,pady=5)
```

Then you need to modify `add()` to insert *parent* and *child* separately:

```py
def add():
    global count
    a = ie3.get()
    try:
        float(a)
        component = ie1.get()
        if not my_tree.exists(component):
            # insert parent
            my_tree.insert(parent="", index="end", iid=component, text=component)
        # insert child
        my_tree.insert(parent=component, index='end', iid=count, values=(ie2.get(),ie3.get(),ie4.get(),ie5.get()))                                                                                         
        count += 1
    except ValueError:
        mesg()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am just beginning my journey in coding and your help really motivates me to keep going. I appreciate your time in taking a look at code and helping beginners like me.

Comment: @balaji If it helps, you are appreciated to accept it as the answer by clicking the *tick* beside the answer.

Comment: Oops, I am new here. I didn't know that. I did it now. Thanks again